# Laravel - How is Kernel created?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In `public\index.php`, I just dump the `$kernel` variable like this:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

dd($kernel);die;
```

The result of passing `$kernel` to `dd()` is `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` not `Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel`. How is  `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel knows how to resolve the instance given the bindings in `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);
```

Comment: But output is `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` ?

Comment: By default the output should be `App\Http\Kernel`. What are the contents of your `bootstrap/app.php` file?